Monotone Class Theorem to Prove Density of Classes of Functions, with Example
Question
I am wondering why the monotone class theorem isn't used more often, and/or if my logic for how it would be used is wrong. It seems like using it is the most efficient way to show, for example, that classes of functions are dense in $L^p$. For example, lets show that the compactly supported and smooth functions, $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, are dense in $L^p$ for $1 \leq p <\infty$.
The Theorem
The monotone class theorem is the following: If $\mathbb{A}$ is a $\pi$-system (non-empty, closed under finite intersections) containing $\Omega$, and $\mathbb{H}$ is a set of functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying three conditions, then $\mathbb{H}$ contains all functions measurable with respect to $\sigma(\mathbb{A})$. The three conditions are the following:

$\mathbb{H}$ must contain all indicator functions for sets in $\mathbb{A}$.
$\mathbb{H}$ must be closed under linear combinations.
$\mathbb{H}$ must be closed under increasing sequences of non-negative functions approaching a bounded limit. I.e. if a set of non-negative $f_n \in \mathbb{H} $ has $f_n \uparrow f$, and $f$ is bounded, then $f \in \mathbb{H}$.

Example
To prove $C_0^{\infty}$ is dense in $L^p$ using the monotone class theorem, take $\mathbb{A}$ to be the open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{H}$ to be the closure of $C_0^{\infty}$ under the $L^P$ norm. We prove conditions easiest to hardest. Condition 2 is clear.
To prove condition 3, take $g_n = f_{n+1}-f_n$ which is in $\mathbb{H}$ by condition 2. Then we have that $f$ is the pointwise limit of $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}g_n$. We now show that this limit is in $L^p$ as well, meaning that $f$ is in $\mathbb{H}$ by the definition of $\mathbb{H}$. For this, take $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_0-f|^p-|f_n-f|^p = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_0-f|^p$$ by monotone convergence, and we have the condition 3.
To prove condition 1, take the indicator function $\chi_{(-1,1)}$. We can scale and translate to get the rest of the open intervals. Take any sequence of increasingly sharp mollifiers belonging to $C_0^{\infty}$ which integrate to 1, for example $M_n(x)=nCexp(-(1-(nx)^2)^{-1})\chi_{(-1,1)}$. The sequence $\chi_{(-1,1)}*M_n(x) \in C^\infty_0$ approaches $\chi_{(-1,1)}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ in the $L_p$ norm by the bounded convergence theorem.
Finally, the monotone class theorem gives us that $\mathbb{H}$ includes all bounded functions measurable with respect to $\sigma(\mathbb{A})$, the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Now if we just prove that bounded functions are dense in $L_p$, we are done! This is easy, since $min(f,n)$ is dominated by $f$, and so approaches it in $L_p$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ by the dominated convergence theorem. We now have that $C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p$ for $1\leq p < \infty$.
Discussion
Note that at the final stage, we proved that the closure of $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ in the $L_p$ norm is all the bounded measurable functions, not just those in $L_p$! Also, if we get rid of the boundedness requirement in condition 3, we extend the conclusion of the theorem to unbounded functions as well, shortening the argument even further.
This seems like an extremely easy way to show that certain functions are dense in some space. The only part which seems like it could be challenging is condition 1, but in practice I have always found it easy. I have seen several authors in various contexts prove results like this with much longer chains of logic which don't generalize well, and the only time I have come across one using monotone class theorem is in Durett's Probability Theory and Examples.
So my question is again twofold: Did I do everything right, and if so, why don't more people use the monotone class theorem to significantly simplify proofs of such results?
Edit: I believe there is a problem with this argument because the indicator function for $\mathbb{R}$ is not in $L_p$. So we could only conclude $C^{\infty}$ is dense in $L_p$ for functions over a bounded domain.

I think part of it might be that we're often interested in showing a property holds for Lebesgue measurable functions, rather than just Borel measurable functions.  Aside from that, I don't think proving the convolution with those mollifiers converge in $L^p$ to $\chi_{(-1,1)}$ is any easier than proving that $f * M_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ for arbitrary bounded measurable $f \in L^p$?

Forgive my ignorance, but shouldn't this not matter since any Lebesgue measurable function is equal a.e. to a Borel measurable function? So the distinction should disappear in $L^p$ where we identify functions up to sets of measure zero.

For $C^{\infty}_c$ specifically, I don’t see why this argument is any easier; in fact I would say it is more difficult since you’re invoking more abstract measure-theoretic results (as wonderful and useful they may be). Your current proof still has some convolution arguments, so you’re not really bypassing the heart of the problem. Also, how can you say the closure of $C^{\infty}_c$ in the $L^p$ norm is all bounded measurable functions? That makes no sense; the closure needs to be a subset of $L^p$.

There are definitely situations where the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem and its consequences (like the monotone class theorem for functions) are useful for proving density of certain types of functions and related results but for me, this is not one of those situations. One useful example I can think of is that (on nice enough spaces) the space $\mathcal{B}$ of bounded Borel functions is the smallest collection of functions which is closed under ‘uniformly bounded pointwise limits’ and which contains $C_b$, the bounded continuous functions. This is nice for e.g proving the Borel functional calculus.

peek-a-boo, thanks for your comment. I realize now the issue with what I did is that the indicator function for all of $\mathbb{R}$ isn't in the closure of $C_0^{\infty}$ in the $L_P$ norm. Hence this proof actually only works for showing density for functions defined on a given bounded region.
